# How can I access the Galarian Star tournament in Pokemon Shield?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield, pokemon-crown-tundra

So, I've been playing Pokemon Sword and Shield, and I purchased the expansion pack in early 2020. On Pokemon Sword, where I had been Champion for months, ended most of the postgame, completed the Isle of Armor, and was currently attempting to fill the pokedex, I finished the Crown Tundra story up until the final legendary clue, which relates to the Ultra Wormhole that appears over the Max Lair. I went outside and got access to the Galarian Star tournament.

More recently, I tried to get the Galarian Star tournament on Pokemon Shield, where I was not yet champion. I completed the story to the same point, yet Leon never called me to invite me to the tournament. So, trying to find the cause of the issue, I became champion, completed the postgame, and completed much of the Isle of Armor. However, I STILL could not get to the Galarian Star tournament. I looked up the requirements to get to the tournament, and I think I've completed all of them, but I can't figure out what I need to do. What steps should I take to get there? If you have any questions about what I have or haven't done, please put them in the comments and I'll add the answers to my description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The requirements are:](https://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-sword-shield/Galarian_Star_Tournament)

- Complete the Isle of Armor story. This is done after winning the last battle against Mustard. This can only be done after completing the non-DLC post-game story (stopping Sordward and Shielbert).
- Start the "They Came From The Ultra Beyond!" quest (the Ultra Wormhole quest) by talking to Peony in the Max Lair.

You had mentioned that you had completed *much* of the Isle of Armor in Shield, but you need to complete *all* of the Isle of Armor story.

Answer (score -1):

Complete the Crown Tundra's main story, then it should become unlocked.P.S. Not sure about this never played tha game before but looked up a answer on the 'net.